# App Bundle contains the following configurations where the initial install would exceed the maximum size of 150 MB

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, google-play

I tried to upload the update version of my app in the playstore but i am receiving the following error as shown in the image.Need help on this.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps your build is really so large. Try reduce app size with this recommendations: https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/reduce-apk-size

Answer (score 2):

Use Google Play Asset Delivery feature instead. More info could be found here

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_play_asset_delivery

https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/asset-delivery